# AWS adding instance via api gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I have function in Lambda. Function is connected to the api gateway and it should add EC2 instance. When im reaching the endpoint by api gateway method test, it returns status 200 but no instance has been added. Maybe the instance params are wrong? Basically the function is modified version of documentation example.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'});

exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {
    // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js

// Load credentials and set region from JSON file

// Create EC2 service object
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

// AMI is amzn-ami-2011.09.1.x86_64-ebs
var instanceParams = {
   InstanceType: 't2.micro',
   KeyName: 'firstkeypair',
   ImageId: 'ami-0bbe28eb2173f6167'
};

// Create a promise on an EC2 service object
var instancePromise = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).runInstances(instanceParams).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
instancePromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
    console.log("Created instance", instanceId);
    // Add tags to the instance
    tagParams = {Resources: [instanceId], Tags: [
       {
          Key: 'Name',
          Value: 'SDK Sample'
       }
    ]};
    // Create a promise on an EC2 service object
    var tagPromise = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).createTags(tagParams).promise();
    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
    tagPromise.then(
      function(data) {
        console.log("Instance tagged");
      }).catch(
        function(err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
      });
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });
}
```

AWS test logs:

```
Execution log for request a83bae6e-2fbf-4d88-ad70-a683a83bdc41
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Starting execution for request: a83bae6e-2fbf-4d88-ad70-a683a83bdc41
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Method request path: {}
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Method request query string: {}
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Method request headers: {}
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Method request body before transformations: 
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:081348884123:function:hello/invocations
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=a83bae6e-2fbf-4d88-ad70-a683a83bdc41, Authorization=**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************59de14, X-Amz-Date=20200816T165600Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=o2hkrbm1o4, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:081348884123:o2hkrbm1o4/test-invoke-stage/GET/, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_o2hkrbm1o4, X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAAaCXVzLWVhc3QtMiJIMEYCIQCPi2S8PtDGsVK3w101D8B05/BCFGyUCzHeX8CT6tC7pAIhAJZCgpbZN94qCVdAgrQGlIIE+ABsO9MDkzh6Lf3WGq3IKr0DCNn//////////wEQARoMNzE4NzcwNDUzMTk1IgxILUqxpu50pB1cJmcqkQP/g+OuOqP7/zXYq8IAzTMolDThuprxjuzwDbmtAmS3adcmmHO25YxBQrId1XiR7ZEU7mq52k4A0nIFhBPkz2dZZIfr8MiLVCDx5tLok8j3lPZJOW+I3n7BVglTMtfQDpPYRSUcIQhOfsSnEEc+FKPzHyrzGsLeazIUHItf5L3xY4QO9tyDWnTXfcM2pp [TRUNCATED]
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Sun Aug 16 16:56:00 UTC 2020 : Sending request to https://lambda.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:081348884123:function:hello/invocations
Sun Aug 16 16:56:02 UTC 2020 : Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 1952 ms
Sun Aug 16 16:56:02 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Sun, 16 Aug 2020 16:56:02 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=4, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=f84212ea-38f8-40cc-b5c6-c12885e78392, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5f396520-4d9dfcb6b965192c5fea0df6;sampled=0}
Sun Aug 16 16:56:02 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: null
Sun Aug 16 16:56:02 UTC 2020 : Method response body after transformations: null
Sun Aug 16 16:56:02 UTC 2020 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5f396520-4d9dfcb6b965192c5fea0df6;Sampled=0, Content-Type=application/json}
Sun Aug 16 16:56:02 UTC 2020 : Successfully completed execution
Sun Aug 16 16:56:02 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*",
                "organizations:DescribeAccount",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganization",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganizationalUnit",
                "organizations:DescribePolicy",
                "organizations:ListChildren",
                "organizations:ListParents",
                "organizations:ListPoliciesForTarget",
                "organizations:ListRoots",
                "organizations:ListPolicies",
                "organizations:ListTargetsForPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:
**Solved by adding EC2 Full Access permission to Lambda Function.**

Comment: So everything in the Lambda works (nothing in the CloudWatch logs) and then in the EC2 service console for us-west-2 theres no instances? :(

Comment: My bad, i didn't check the function in lambda but only in api geteway. The MaxCount and MinCount was missing but after adding those parameters i got an error: "You are not authorized to perform this operation."

Comment: Has your Lambda the IAM permissions?

Comment: My Lambda function have role with IAMFullAccess permissions

Comment: Could you put the IAM policy? :)

Comment: I added it into the post content.

Comment: Ok it work's now. I've  added EC2 full access :)

Comment: Great I am glad it is resolved, try to limit the permissions down to the minimal you require though as the EC2 full access permission adds over permissions that can be dangerous such as modification to network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 issues as discovered through the comments.

The first was that the `RunInstances` task was not including the MinCount and MaxCount properties which led to no instances being launched.

Once this was fixed the next issue was a permissions issue due to the lack of permissions to run `ec2:RunInstance` or `e2:CreateTags`.

It is worth stating the best practice with permissions is to scope down to the minimal permissions that you require to successfully run.